# Verificar Consistência de um backup SQL Server em C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

Como posso fazer a verficação de integridade do arquivo de backup de um banco SQL Server em C#??
Usei o seguinte `namespace` e classes para gerar o backup:

```
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo {
  ServerConnection
  Server
  Backup
  BackupDeviceItem }
```

Gostaria de saber como verifico o arquivo BACKUP010101.BKP por exemplo.
Pensei em algo do tipo [RESTORE VERIFYONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188902.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), mas não sei como fazer dentro C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um teste aqui com esse código e funciona, é só um exemplo.

Altere ele para ficar de acordo com o que você exatamente quer.

Ele está usando RESTORE VERIFYONLY que você quer, o comando vai verificar o backup, se estiver bom ele retorna 'OK', se não, vai retornar a mensagem de erro do Sql Server.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString1 = (@"Data Source =localhost; Initial Catalog = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString1);
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = @"begin try RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'c:\home\bkp.bak' SELECT 'OK'; end try begin catch select ERROR_MESSAGE(); end catch";

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        var resultado = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        MessageBox.Show(resultado.ToString());
        cn.Close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;  
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;  
using System;  

class A {  
   public static void Main() {  
      // Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server.   
      Server srv = new Server();  

      // Reference the AdventureWorks2012 database.             
      Database db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2012"];  

      // Note, to use the StringCollection type the System.Collections.Specialized system namespace must be included in the imports statements.   
      System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc;  

      // Run the CheckTables method and display the results from the returned StringCollection variable.   
      sc = db.CheckTables(RepairType.None);  

      foreach (string c in sc) {  
         Console.WriteLine(c);  
      }  
   }  
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx